# What's the correct way of writing following sentence :

Tags: sentence-construction

> I'm reading them (documents) as they are being posted.

OR

> I'm reading them (documents) as they being posted.

OR

> I'm reading them (documents) as they have being posted.

OR

> I'm reading them (documents) as they have been posted."

If none of the above, then how?

Answer (score 1):

The first option is correct - as *they are being posted*.

The second is wrong as it is missing the verb "are".

The last option is grammatically correct but means something different from what you intend. "*I'm reading them as they have been posted*" means "I am reading the documents **only because** they have been posted", implying that you wouldn't have read them otherwise (for example, you only read documents from a screen and not from hard copy). This could also mean that documents which have been posted have been approved and that you don't read unapproved documents.

Answer (score 1):

The first clause of the sentence "I am reading them" is in present continuous tense. In this sentence, **as** is a conjunction that requires a clause (something containing a verb) on the right hand side: it means **at the same time as**, so we need a clause in the same time frame, so present simple or present continuous would work.

> I'm reading them as they are being posted. - present continuous
>
> I'm reading them as they are posted. - present simple

Option two doesn't work because we need a verb to make a clause on the right hand side. Option three "have being posted" isn't a valid tense at all, and four is a past tense, so it doesn't work.